# Blur image with pure c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to blur an image. At this point, I can blur it without a border. I read that I can achieve my goal by putting my data container into a bigger data container. I tried it, but I couldn't do it successfully. Maybe someone knows an easier solution to do this? Here's my code:

```
Image Blur::transform(const Image &inputImage)
{
    Image input = (inputImage.type != ImageType::Grayscale)
            ? Grayscale().transform(inputImage)
            : inputImage;

    std::cout << "Blurring" << std::endl;

    Image output = input;

    auto indexAt = [&input](int row, int col) { return row * input.size.m_width + col; };

    for (int row = m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; row < output.size.m_height - m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; col < output.size.m_width - m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; col++)
        {
            std::vector<uint8_t> pixel_values;
            for (int row_offset = -m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; row_offset <= m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; row_offset++)
            {
                for (int col_offset = -m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; col_offset <= m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; col_offset++)
                {
                    const int offset_pixel_index = indexAt(row + row_offset, col + col_offset);
                    pixel_values.push_back(input.data[offset_pixel_index]);
                }
            }

            const int center_pixel_index = indexAt(row, col);
            output.data[center_pixel_index] = getModifiedValue(pixel_values);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Where `Image` is as below:

```
struct Image
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    Size size;
    ImageType type;

    int pixelCount() const {
        return size.m_height * size.m_width;
    }

    Image() {}
    Image(Size _size, ImageType _type) : size(_size), type(_type) {}
    ~Image() {}
};

struct Size
{
    int m_width;
    int m_height;

    Size() {}
    Size(int width, int height) : m_width(width), m_height(height) {}
};

enum class ImageType
{
    Rgba,
    Grayscale
};
```

So can you help?

Comment: If you tried it, you should post the code that you wrote that didn't work. Otherwise the sole mention doesn't mean much. And you don't need a bigger container just to blur an image, an edge checking condition will do.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz tried it last week. Unfortunately don't have that code already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is your question, if you want to blur it, blur it with borders or without borders, so I will try to answer on both methods.

Firstly, when you blur on borders you need to assume what are values behind borders. Usually you reuse border value.

```
x index -2 | -1  | 0  |  1 |  2  
        ---------------------------
  color ?  |  ?  | C1 | C2 | C3
```

So copy C1 to -1, -2 indices

```
x index -2 | -1  | 0  |  1 |  2  
        ---------------------------
  color C1 | C1  | C1 | C2 | C3
```

That is,

> I can achieve my goal by putting my data container into bigger data
>   container

You do it by creating new image bigger image and copy border values to out-of-border ones. You blur internal part of it (on source indicies [0,N]) and then discard out-of-border values (as they are not relevant in original image).

3x3 image example:

```
C1 | C2 | C3
------------
C5 | C5 | C6
------------
C7 | C8 | C9
```

Add 1 blur radius

```
C1 | C1 | C2 | C3 | C3
----------------------
C1 | C1 | C2 | C3 | C3
----------------------
C5 | C5 | C5 | C6 | C6
----------------------
C7 | C7 | C8 | C9 | C9
----------------------
C7 | C7 | C8 | C9 | C9
```

Now you calculate blur of 5x image with 3x3 boxes on indices on indicies [1,3] and write it as blurred image with 3x3. This is what your function almost already does (except resizing).

Blur via putting into greater container:

```
Image transformWithExtending(const Image &inputImage)
{
    Image input = (inputImage.type != ImageType::Grayscale)
        ? Grayscale().transform(inputImage)
        : inputImage;
    Image newInput = Image({ input.size.m_width + 2 * m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS, input.size.m_height + 2 * m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS }, input.type);

    auto indexAt = [&input](int row, int col) { return row * input.size.m_width + col; };
    auto clamp = [&input](int x, int minv, int maxv) {return std::min(std::max(x, minv), maxv); } // std::clamp is only in C++17
    // indexing in source image (with negatives)
    for (int row = -m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; row < input.size.m_height + m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; row++)
        for (int col = -m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; col < input.size.m_width + m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; col++)
            newInput.data.push_back(input.data[indexAt(clamp(row, 0,input.size.m_width - 1), clamp(row, 0, input.size.m_height - 1))]);


    // now transform it with previous function
    Transform(newInput)

    // and resize...
    // TODO
    //
    return output;
}
```

But now you can ask yourself: why copy all this data to temporary image, if you can get same result by selection border pixels instead of one-of-border ones when filling filter box values? Simply clamp indicies out-of-border to border ones. Which gives:

Blur without putting into greater container: (only few lanes changes from your function)

```
Image Blur::transformWithBorders(const Image &inputImage)
{
    Image input = (inputImage.type != ImageType::Grayscale)
        ? Grayscale().transform(inputImage)
        : inputImage;

    std::cout << "Blurring" << std::endl;

    Image output = input;

    auto indexAt = [&input](int row, int col) { return row * input.size.m_width + col; };
    auto clamp = [&input](int x, int minv, int maxv) {return std::min(std::max(x, minv), maxv); } // std::clamp is only in C++17

    for (int row = 0; row < output.size.m_height; row++) // go over whole image
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < output.size.m_width; col++) // go over whole image
        {
            std::vector<uint8_t> pixel_values;
            for (int row_offset = -m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; row_offset <= m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; row_offset++)
            {
                for (int col_offset = -m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; col_offset <= m_BLUR_MASK_RADIUS; col_offset++)
                {
                    // and clamp indicies here
                    const int offset_pixel_index = indexAt(clamp(row + row_offset, 0, output.size.m_height - 1), clamp(col + col_offset,0, output.size.m_width - 1));
                    pixel_values.push_back(input.data[offset_pixel_index]);
                }
            }

            const int center_pixel_index = indexAt(row, col);
            output.data[center_pixel_index] = getModifiedValue(pixel_values);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank's ! Great solution